# PCRE regular expression with exponential running time

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Regular expression implementations using recursive backtracking can exhibit exponential running time in some cases.

I'm trying to find such a pathological regular expression for the PCRE engine.

I've tried several regexes, which are known to be exponential for Perl regular expressions (e.g. [this one](http://perlgeek.de/blog-en/perl-tips/in-search-of-an-exponetial-regexp.html)), but none of them exhibited exponential runtime with PCRE in my tests.

Comment: @BartKiers I saw that page I tried some of them, but none were exponential. For example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/N4CCUi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your tests, were all the regexes expected to fail?  And when they did fail, did you find out exactly why?  Maybe the matches are failing *because* the regex engine detected excessive backtracking.  I don't know if that ever happens, but try a regex that should succeed, like this one:

```
(?i)lorem(?:.|\s)*pri\.
```

Using RegexBuddy, I applied that regex to the first paragraph of the text below and it highlighted the whole paragraph as expected.  When I removed the period at the end of the paragraph, the highlighting went out and the debugger said it had given up after a million operations.  No surprise there, but when I put the period back and added the second paragraph, it still failed--too much backtracking again.

---

> Lorem ipsum tritani impedit civibus ei pri, legimus antiopam no sed, quo id everti forensibus maiestatis. Vim ad intellegat consequuntur. Te dicam impedit inciderint mea. Usu prompta alterum contentiones no, ut esse fabellas splendide pri.
>
> Ne utroque nominavi moderatius qui, ius at suas velit nihil, vidit blandit facilisi pri ut. Ad vel offendit reprehendunt, mea ex quem ipsum complectitur. Veri cetero feugait cu usu, in dolor corpora adolescens vim, at sit voluptua placerat sadipscing. Minim admodum constituam eos ut, vix ut movet causae tractatos, in pro dicat dicta dolores. Impetus praesent eum no.

Comment: Thanks, the backtracking limit was indeed the issue. Stupid me. Here is a nice example of the execution time doubling every time: http://codepad.viper-7.com/3PePHQ